# In Mac Debugging is not working in VS Code

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

command flutter run is working.
Debug working in Android Studio.

When I debug emulator or simulator from vs code then its launching but then nothing is happening.

```
Waiting for a connection from Flutter on sdk gphone64 arm64...
```

I have tried,

I have configured flutter with vs code.

Added dart, flutter extensions in vs code.

Added global path for flutter.

launch.json

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Dart: Attach to Process",
            "type": "dart",
            "request": "attach"
        },
        {
            "name": "Dart",
            "type": "dart",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "bin/main.dart"
        },
        {
            "name": "app",
            "request": "attach",
            "type": "dart"
        }
    ]
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: You should use Android Studio for best experience of debugging.

Comment: Yeah you are right. I use Android Studio for emulator. I want to debug in my iphone device.

Comment: For iPhone also you can use Android Studio in any Mac.

Comment: when I try to debug from android studio I got error :  WARNING: CocoaPods requires your terminal to be using UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: That is because you need to add         " export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8     "         these lines to your profiles file of mac using your terminal.

Comment: okay, working in android studio. thankyou.

Comment: posting it as an answer

Answer (score 1):

For debugging using Android Studio in iPhone do this :

In any of the mac profile that you use, you need to add these 3 lines :

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8 
export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8 
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

Then your error will be removed while running in iPhone using Android Studio.